# Trying to include multiple html pages in vite build

Tags: javascript, vite, rollupjs

This works ok, but is there a better way to process all the html files?

```
// vite.config.js
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
        contact: resolve(__dirname, "contact.html"),
        blog: resolve(__dirname, "font-sizes.html"),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have tried other ideas on stack overflow, but they do not work.

Comment: Better how? What is it about this configuration that wants you to seek an alternative?

Comment: Outomatically include html files in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that reads all of your html files and returns **an object** as vite expect

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

function getHtmlEntries() {
  const pagesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "");
  const entries = {};

  // Read all files in the directory
  const files = fs.readdirSync(pagesDir);

  // Filter out HTML files
  const htmlFiles = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(".html"));

  // Create entries for each HTML file
  htmlFiles.forEach((file) => {
    const name = path.basename(file, ".html");
    entries[name] = path.resolve(pagesDir, file);
  });

  return entries;
}
```

**Note:** on pagesDir variable put the directory name if your html files on another directory or leave it blank as it is :)

Thats it. Now put that function to rollup input config.

```
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: getHtmlEntries()
    }
}
```